# How to get working UA741CP IC

Tags: voltage, amplifier, oscillator, feedback, phase-shift

Recently I've decided to build a simple RC oscillator circuit using UA741CP IC as an amplifier in my circuit. I think the way I connected the resistors and capacitors to the chip is correct. But the only thing that is not correct is power supply. You see, I've been told to power the chip by two separate power supplies. Even if I did this, the circuit wasn't working and it was drawing 0A. Nothing was working.

Schematic I connected it according to:

[image]

UA741CP pinout:

[image]

Now the way I have my circuit connected:
[image]

My power supply looks like this:

[image]

If you know the solutions, please let me know and explain it to me in details so I can continue in my work. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know it isn't oscillating?  Did you look at the output with an oscilloscope?  The current display of a power supply isn't precise enough to show the few milliamperes this circuit will draw.

Comment: The output was steady, nothing moved. There must be a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that's a dual power supply, I think it's a single power supply with a chassis earth terminal between the two output terminals.

You need a supply with positive and negative outputs or two supplies that you can connect in series (the minus terminal must not be grounded for that to work).

You can verify by measuring the voltage from -V to GND and +V to GND with a multimeter.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work. What do you suggest? Is it necessary to have a dual power supply like this one? Can I somehow do it?

Comment: A dual power supply is the best way. Another way is to create a pseudo ground. In this particular case you can replace each R with 2 pieces 20K resistor, one to the minus rail and one to the plus rail. (ah, I see @Andy made the exact same suggestion whilst I slept).

Answer (score 3):

The main problem you have with your design (other than power supply issues) is that there is no DC feedback to the inverting input and your op-amp is therefore going to be hard against one of the power rails due to input offset voltages causing a small input offset to be magnified by the open loop gain to some ridiculous figure.

It seems that you got the circuit from [this site](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/rc_oscillator.html) and further down they give a more useful and realizable circuit: -

[image]

Notice the feedback resistor Rf.

Also, if you do want to run this from a single supply, replace the 10 kohm resistor at the 180 deg node with two 20 kohm resistors; one connected to ground (as per the current 10 kohm resistor) and one from the voltage supply to the 180 deg node.

Comment: May I ask? Would my circuit be able to provide 1MHz with a proper components?

Comment: Yes, but not a 741 or anything like it.

Comment: What would you suggest.. what chip? I heard this one is pretty old and quite hard to maintain

Comment: Well, the gain needs to be 29 at 1 MHz (Rf is 290 kohm compared to R at 10 kohm) and so the open loop op-amp gain would need to be at least double this at around 60 so, you would be looking for an op-amp with a gain bandwidth product of above 60 MHz and quite possibly something around 100 MHz is something to go for. However, the circuit I've added is still not sufficient for many applications and yours might be one of them. For instance, there is no circuitry that controls sinewave amplitude and most applications will need it. What is your application?

Comment: I want this as a school project. I think you've already noticed I'm a student. I want to have an RC oscillator with a decent voltage output.

Comment: Well you need a better op-amp so go down this route but, at least prove you can get it working from a single rail following my advice.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you said back there.. I connect the resistor 20k to the 60 deg point.. and then another resistor after the R1 to create a voltage divider?

Comment: Since the first two 10k resistors are AC coupled I think you can leave them alone. Just change the third one (at 180º) to a 20k to ground plus a 20k to Vcc (joined at op amp -in) to create a bias voltage at 1/2 Vcc while still having a total of 10k at that point. Vcc should be 10V or higher.

Comment: @BruceAbbott good point